# How to get sub variable (title) of array node js?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a code like this

```
const arrayTable = {
        array1 : ['A1', 'A2'],
        array2 : ['B1', 'B2'],
        array3: ['C1', 'C2'],
```

I want call this sub variable "array1, array2, ..." and input that data to new variable :

```
var arrayTitle = 'array1', 'array2', 'array3', ...
```

```
var arrayTitle = 'array1', 'array2', 'array3', ...
```

Comment: use Object.keys(array)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are looking for. Are you looking for the object keys? Just do `Object.keys(arrayTable);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Object.keys

```js
var arrayTitle = Object.keys({
  array1: ['A1', 'A2'],
  array2: ['B1', 'B2'],
  array3: ['C1', 'C2'],
});
console.log(arrayTitle);
```